# How to use SQL result as JSON in .Net

Tags: json, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

With this query I able to select result as JSON.

```
string strQuery = "declare @json varchar(max) = (select field1 from table1 FOR JSON AUTO)print @json";
```

How could to use this result on .Net and what type of parameter should use instead of `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

```
using (TestEntities objEntities = new TestEntities())
        {
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject strJson = objEntities.Database.SqlQuery<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>(strQuery).FirstOrDefault();
            Response.Write(strJson.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: `print` and `raiserror` output are accessed via the [SqlConnection.InfoMessage event hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage). Have you tried just selecting it? e.g.: `select (select field1 from table1 for json auto) as MyColumnName`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning So thank you. Please post it as answer. And if it's possible add varchar(max), so there is not limitation for result. Thanks

Comment: Why would you use `PRINT` rather than `SELECT`? `PRINT` is designed for informational debugging messages, not for normal data transfer, the max length is 4000 as documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this as a string, then deserialize it afterwards if you need to. But you are in any case `ToString`-ing it, so there is no point deserializing it at all. Just keep it as a string.

Furthermore, `PRINT` has a maximum of 8000 bytes (4000 Unicode characters), and is intended for informational messages, it is not designed for data transfer. Use `SELECT` instead.

You should also pass JSON as `nvarchar(max)`

```cs
using (TestEntities objEntities = new TestEntities())
{
    const string strQuery = @"
declare @json nvarchar(max) = (
    select field1
    from table1
    FOR JSON AUTO
);
select @json;
";
    var result = objEntities.Database.SqlQuery<string>(strQuery).FirstOrDefault();
    Response.Write(result);
    // alternatively
    var strJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(result);
}
```

> Don't be tempted to just do a bare `SELECT` with `FOR JSON`, as it has issues when the result is over 2000 characters. You must put it in a variable first.

Comment: So thank you, fantastic answer and description.